# slime doesn't work in emacs24

Tags: emacs, slime, emacs24

I use emacs24 in archlinux.If i use the slime packages from marmalade.org,then when i use M-x slime the error is:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING {AB007A9}>:
  Couldn't load
  "/home/sinners/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20100404.1/swank-loader.lisp": file does
  not exist.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

but if i use the slime-cvs packages from the offical site,the error is:

```
Debugger entered: (("Error in timer" slime-attempt-connection (#<process inferior-lisp> nil 2) (void-variable --cl-accu--)))
  #[257 "\302\303\304\300\301F\"\207" [slime-attempt-connection (#<process inferior-lisp> nil 2) debug nil "Error in timer"] 7 "\n\n(fn DATA)"]((void-variable --cl-accu--))
  funcall(#[257 "\302\303\304\300\301F\"\207" [slime-attempt-connection (#<process inferior-lisp> nil 2) debug nil "Error in timer"] 7 "\n\n(fn DATA)"] (void-variable --cl-accu--))
  slime-timer-call(slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 2)
  apply(slime-timer-call (slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 2))
  byte-code("r\301\302H\303H\"\210)\301\207" [timer apply 5 6] 4)
  timer-event-handler([t 20271 59188 161536 0.3 slime-timer-call (slime-attempt-connection #<process inferior-lisp> nil 2) nil])
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 10):

Problem with `--cl-accu--` variable signs about breakage of emacs cl package in presence of lexical scoping. Try to go to `slime.el` in your slime distribution, find string 
`;; lexical-binding: t` in the `;; Local Variables:` section at the end of the file and change it to `;; lexical-binding: nil`. And remove old `slime.elc` file if you have one.

Comment: this works after i add (slime-setup '(slime-fancy)) to .emacs.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem, which was solved by deleting the slime.elc file, that I had compiled earlier using byte-recompile-directory. I didn't try compiling it again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but this problem can be due to different versions of `SLIME` and `SWANK`. However you should just use `pacman` to install a lisp implementation ­(I think that [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) is the most popular implementation on Linux) and then use [`quicklisp`](http://www.quicklisp.org/) to install everything else.

See [this](http://www.mohiji.org/2011/01/modern-common-lisp-on-linux/) blog post to see how to install `SWANK` and `SLIME` with `quicklisp`.

Comment: but i can't use slime first,so there is means to talk about quicklisp

Comment: SLIME and Quicklisp are two things totally different and independant. SLIME uses SWANK as an interface between Emacs and the Lisp process. And Quicklisp is a library manager which uses ASDF. You can, and you should use Quicklisp to install everything related to Common Lisp, SWANK and SLIME included. In the link I gave above, its author explains how to install SLIME and `quicklisp-slime-helper` and how to use them with Emacs.

Comment: yeah,i understand.Now the slime works.I will try quicklisp when i know some basic lisp.